Flutter: Implementing Filters in AppBar with Scroll and Hide Functionality
I need to implement filters at the top of the screen. The idea is that when you scroll down, the filters should disappear, but the title and leading widget should remain visible. Additionally, when scrolling up, the filters should reappear. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this, what is the best use for this for this feature?

I answered a similar question. Please take a look:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/77914748/12349734 . It shows/hides the appbar based on if your scrolling or not

you achive this using ScrollController  to detect scroll direction and a combination of SliverAppBar and SliverPersistentHeader for the layout.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScrollableFiltersPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScrollableFiltersPageState createState() => _ScrollableFiltersPageState();
}

class _ScrollableFiltersPageState extends State<ScrollableFiltersPage> {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  bool _showFilters = true;
  double _lastOffset = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.offset > _lastOffset && _showFilters) {
        setState(() => _showFilters = false); // Scrolling down
      } else if (_scrollController.offset < _lastOffset && !_showFilters) {
        setState(() => _showFilters = true); // Scrolling up
      }
      _lastOffset = _scrollController.offset;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            title: Text('Title'),
            leading: Icon(Icons.menu),
          ),
          SliverPersistentHeader(
            pinned: true,
            delegate: _FiltersDelegate(
              showFilters: _showFilters,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                height: 50,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Filter 1")),
                    TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Filter 2")),
                    TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Filter 3")),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text('Item $index')),
              childCount: 50,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


class _FiltersDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final bool showFilters;
  final Widget child;

  _FiltersDelegate({required this.showFilters, required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return AnimatedOpacity(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      opacity: showFilters ? 1.0 : 0.0,
      child: child,
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 50.0;
  @override
  double get minExtent => 50.0;
  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant _FiltersDelegate oldDelegate) =>
      showFilters != oldDelegate.showFilters || child != oldDelegate.child;
}

I HOPE THIS IS HELP YOU.
THANK YOU:)

Thank you so much.... that's it, it works perfectly

@e Ras don't forget to accept the answer to help others too

You can achieve this functionality using the new PinnedHeaderSliver and SliverResizingHeader widgets introduced in Flutter 3.24. These widgets allow you to design dynamic App Bars where headers can float, stay pinned, or resize as the user scrolls.
Implementation Steps:

Use PinnedHeaderSliver: This keeps your title and leading widget always visible at the top.
Use SliverResizingHeader: Place your filters inside this widget so they disappear when scrolling down and reappear when scrolling up.

These new widgets provide a simpler and more flexible interface compared to the existing SliverPersistentHeader and SliverAppBar.
 For a practical example, check out the PinnedHeaderSliver code that recreates the effect of the settings bar in iOS apps.
References:

Flutter Slivers Documentation
Flutter 3.24 Release Notes

